# Get current vimscript script name and line number?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, functions, echo

In C programming language, it's typical to log a message with filename and line number of the source code file the message is coming from:

```
#define log(fmt, ...)  printf("%s:%d: " fmt "\n", __file__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

I would want to do that in vimscript.

```
function! log(msg) abort
    echom previous_vimscript_name().':'.previous_vimscript_line().': '.msg
endfunction
```

How would I do that? `echom` only prints the message, I would want to print where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! You can use `expand('<sfile>')` and `expand('<sflnum>')` see `h sfile` for all the expanded stuff you can use. But instead use:

```
function! log(msg) abort
    echom expand('<stack>').': '.msg
endfunction
```

`stack` will give you the whole nice looking stack:

```
/home/kamil/.config/nvim/init.vim[6]../home/kamil/.vimrc[464]..function kc#log: Hello world
```

I settled for the following, to also remove `function kc#log` from the output:

```
echom substitute(expand("<sfile>"), '\.\.[^.]*$', "", "").": ".a:str
```